# Scilab 5.5.2 doesn't work on Mac OS X 10.11

Tags: macos, scilab, osx-elcapitan

I try to run Scilab 5.5.2 on Mac OS X after the update to 10.11 version and an alert feedback pop up with this text "This version of Scilab will probably fail on this system (10.11): Scilab requires 10.6.5 (Snow Leopard) or newer system."

I try to reinstall the scilab application and the JVM v8 update 60, but no improvement happened.

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got Scilab 5.5.2 working on my Mac with OS X 10.11 by doing the following:

1. Installed the Scilab 5.5.2 version recommended for OS X 10.10 Yosemite
2. Installed the legacy v6 Java, found [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US) on the Apple Support website (no need to remove Java v8)
3. Starting Scilab gives the warning "This version of Scilab will probably fail on this system (10.11): Scilab requires 10.6.5 (Snow Leopard) or newer system.", but choosing the option "Try anyway" Scilab opens, and runs without any issues

Comment: I tried as you suggested but the application closes after clicking the button "Try anyway"

Comment: @Cavs85 Did you install the version specific to Yosemite? You'll have to follow "Other systems" link [http://www.scilab.org/download/latest] in order to get it. The download link on the homepage doesn't work even with the Java 6 update.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the above instruction by installing legacy v6 Java. Then I launched Scilab and got the same result. It still did not work.

So I dragged Scilab icon to the trash can and reinstalled. I could make it work that way.

Comment: Reinstalling Scilab-5.5.2 for Yosemite the application works!

Comment: For the record, I am actually using the el capitan. When I clicked on the try anyway button, Scilab console appeared and things worked normally.

Answer (score 0):

One of the comments [here](https://www.facebook.com/Scilab/posts/1241161885934003) proposes to run the following command:

```
cp /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib /Applications/scilab-5.5.2.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/thirdparty/
```

Worked successfully for me.